# Windows 10 Taskbar not working properly

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Okay, so this one is kind of more complicated to solve than the other questions. Like the others, my Windows 10 taskbar is COMPLETELY unresponsive, but the thing that is different is this:

1. My function keys will not work.
2. I cannot open task manager without it crashing and not even loading up.
3. My Windows key will not work, so anything stating "Use the Windows Key + (insert key)" will not work for me.

   I've spent 5 hours on this download and I cannot rollback to Windows 8.1 due to me being unable to use the taskbar or anything else.

Comment: Can you open the start menu with a mouse? start -> Settings > Update & security” > Recovery > Go back to Windows 8.1 > Get started. You can do all of that with just the mouse.

Comment: No I cannot. Like I said, the entire taskbar is unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your is working

1. Open `powershell` with **administrator rights**
2. `Paste` the following command in `powershell` and press `ENTER`:

   Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest­.xml"}

Give it 1 min then everything is back to normal.

This short video will show you how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9n0TZKvKPk